# Insert Data into SQL Table with primary key column

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I have a table in a SQL Server database and an R script that appends data to that tabl.

The db table contains a primary key ("ID"), which is just a scope_identity field

When I try to append the table into that location, I keep running into the following  error

```
>       sqlSave(Conn[["DbCon"]],
+               dat = OutputDataFinal,
+               tablename = "DataSci_StandardTransferPriority",
+               verbose = TRUE,
+               append = TRUE,
+               rownames = FALSE)
Query:
    INSERT INTO "DataSci_StandardTransferPriority" (
        "ID", "LeadSourceName", "AgeCategory", "ZipColor", "LeadCount_Sum",
        "OB_TotalDials_Sum", "ContactRate", "TransferRate", "HypTransfers", "LaborCPT",
        "MarketingCpt", "CloseRate", "PDLTR", "Policy_Count_Sum", "InboundDials_Sum",
        "LeadCost_Sum", "PPT", "PPH", "ContactRateXCloseRate", "ContactRateXCloseRateTarget",
        "ModelValue", "SourcePriority", "InsertTS"
    )
    VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )
Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  : 
  missing columns in 'data'
```

How can I append and ignore the issue with the primary key?

Comment: Your INSERT INTO column list contains 23 columns, but the VALUES list only contains 22 values. Are you attempting to provide an "ID" value directly, or do you intent that ID be set  automatically as an IDENTITY field. If the latter, and your 22 values align with the remaining columns, I think you just need to drop "ID" from the column list.

Answer (score 0):

In standard `INSERT` operation dont specify identity column. It automatically provides next incremental identity value. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
  [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [Column1] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Column2] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TempTable (
  [Column1],
  [Column2]
)
VALUES
  ('first insert', 50.2),
  ('second insert', 84.2);

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

The result was:

| ID | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first insert | 50.200 |
| 2 | second insert | 84.200 |

If you want insert on identity column any way - enable `IDENTITY_INSERT`. But be care for data integrity issues.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
  [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [Column1] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Column2] [decimal](19, 3) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TempTable (
  [Column1],
  [Column2]
)
VALUES ('first insert', 50.2);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable ON;
INSERT INTO #TempTable (
  [ID],
  [Column1],
  [Column2]
)
VALUES
  (4, 'second insert', 84.63),
  (2, 'third insert', 99.56);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable OFF;

INSERT INTO #TempTable (
  [Column1],
  [Column2]
)
VALUES ('four insert', 100.32);

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

And the result:

| ID | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first insert | 50.200 |
| 2 | third insert | 99.560 |
| 4 | second insert | 84.630 |
| 5 | four insert | 100.320 |